# Loop through Data Labels, Choose next Row

Tags: loops, range, label

The current arguments work for the first bar chart:

```
 ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).ApplyDataLabels
 ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Select
 ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange. _
    InsertChartField msoChartFieldRange, "='Percent of Total Change'!$E$4", 0
```

Where "='Percent of Total Change'!$E$4" is the sheet location and cell where the label is located. Note: The default label is as a value, I want to choose my value based on a selected cell / range.

The problem arises when I want to loop through the labels, E4 + n {where n = 1 To 19}
For the .Values code, I have used:

```
  .Values = Range("='Percent of Total Change'!$D$3").Offset(n, 0)
```

But VBA will not allow me to use this offset for the labels.

I am also attempting to use Cell(4 + n, 5) to loop through as well.

Comment: 'LABELS

Set S1 = Range("='Percent of Total Change'!$E$3").Offset(n, 0)
S1 = (FormatPercent(S1, 1))
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).HasDataLabels = True
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels(1).Text = S1

Comment: How can I skip a series? And then skip having to label it, but have the next series index remain? Series(1), Series(2), Series(3) - Skip, Series(4)...NOT Series(3).